# 100% disk usage on Windows 10 without any apps using it

Tags: windows, windows-10

I had a very old Win 10 version, I upgraded to a new one, new one was messed up, screen wouldn't work well and system was completely unresponsive. So I did a fresh installation from a USB, latest Windows version 1709, it worked fine, until yesterday. It's not a problem with the HDD because it works fine on Ubuntu and worked fine on the previous Windows.

The problem: Computer turns extremely slow, practically unusable, task manager shows 100% disk usage, but there are no apps using it.

- I have tried disabling superfetch, Windows Defender, updating drivers. Nothing worked. Like I said, there are no processes using the disk, not superfetch, nor system or anything else.
- I have tried using resmon but it didn't show any processes using the disk, Process Explorer didn't even show the 100% usage.

I have noticed that the problem only happens if I let my computer idle for a couple of minutes, even without it going to sleep or letting the screen dim. If I actively use the computer, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer  Use this and report back.  What about anti-virus or anti-malware software?  What does task manager look like?  System specs?

Comment: I used Process Explorer, I assume I/O is the disk? It shows normal I/O during the 100% bug, doesn't show 100% usage. I have no antivirus installed, it's a fresh installation, barely anything is installed. i7 6500u 2.50 GHz, 8GB RAM, AMD R5 M335

Comment: Hard Drive or Solid State?

Comment: Sounds like maintenance tasks, such as updating, virus scanning and defragmentation are happening in the background, and your disk is not very fast.

Comment: Defrag your HDD.

Comment: run CrystalDiskInfo and look if you have SMART errors

Comment: @magicandre1981CrystalDiskInfo shows everything as OK except for `Current Pending Sector Count`, current value is `100`, worst is `100`, threshold is `0`. It shows this under a yellow light which says `Caution`. I have no idea what this means. I have noticed that every time this bug happens, I get an error in event viewer under `Disk` that says `The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block.` I have run a chkdsk twice and it didn't seem to display anything.

Comment: I've posted an answer. replace the HDD, it may fail sooner or later. Get a SSD which is a lot faster and 100% disk usage perf issues are gone.

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` to confirm your install is OK. How about services? In safe mode does the same thing occur? Granted SF stops alot of servives and processes but should be fine. Also check your `hiberfs.sys` or whatever for issues/recreate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Current Pending Sector Count` [is causing your perf issue](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9133):

> Current Pending Sector Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter is a critical
>   parameter and indicates the **current count of unstable sectors
>   (waiting for remapping)**. The raw value of this attribute indicates
>   the total **number of sectors waiting for remapping. Later, when some
>   of these sectors are read successfully, the value is decreased. If
>   errors still occur when reading some sector, the hard drive will try
>   to restore the data, transfer it to the reserved disk area (spare
>   area) and mark this sector as remapped.**

So you have 100 unstable sectors where the HDD tries to read the data and store the data somewhere else.

> Degradation of this parameter may indicate imminent **drive failure.
>   Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.**

So backup the data and replace the HDD with a new drive. Best is to buy a SSD which is faster.

Comment: I've only had this laptop for a year and half, can't it possibly be a software issue? Especially since this only started happening after I installed a new Win 10, and it doesn't happen on Ubuntu (I have dual boot). Shouldn't Ubuntu also be affected if it is actually hardware?

Comment: when using a laptop it can happen that the HDD got a stroke/push and this could cause HDD damages. maybe the unstable sectors contain windows related data/drivers and so you don't see it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @magicandre1981 To check that the culprit is actually unstable sectors, it should be possible to check the `Current Pending Sector Count` somehow?

Comment: @Juhl run [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/download/#CrystalDiskInfo) and look if you have SMART errors